Какой алгоритм хэширования вычесляется лучше на CPU чем на GPU?
Я хочу найти алгоритм хэширования, который вычесляется на процессоре быстрее или не сильно медленее чем на GPU. Я знаю что примером такого является RandomX, но я не нашёл реализации на C, к тому же все реализации что я нашёл были очень громоздкими (мегабайты кода). Подскажите что-то маленькое и функциональное

Компактное считается быстро на гпу потому что помещается в кеш полностью
